# Query Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase

me surge una duda con respecto a esta query ya que no logro entender como se me cuela un dato que no debería pasar.
mínimo="01/06/2019"
máximo="01/08/2019"

```
  Query rangoDatos = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(nodos.nodoControl).orderByChild(nodos.nodoControl_fecha).startAt(minimo).endAt(maximo);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando recorro los datos con addForSingleListener y los meto en un listview ,me coge también el objeto el cual la fecha es 02/01/2019 y no debería ser así ya que le he indicado que recoja en un rango determinado.

```
rangoDatos.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    datosControl.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Control c = snapshot.getValue(Control.class);
                        if (c.getDni().equalsIgnoreCase(dni)) {
                            datosControl.add(c);
                        }
                    }
                }
                listaFechas.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

Podéis ayudarme,gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las fechas deberian ser guardadas en formato timestamp en la base de datos, por ejemplo, la fecha de hoy se da por el siguiente valor `1559567258`.

Firebase no tiene forma de ordenar esos strings, pero si puede hacerlo con timestamps, para eso , modifica tu modelo para que convierta tu `Date` a `Timestamp`

### Ejemplo para convertir las fechas

```
String str_date="01-06-2019";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date); 
long timestamp = date.getTime() / 1000;
```

Una vez guardes tus fechas de esta forma, vas a poder ordenarlas en Firebase con tu `Query`

### Hint

Podes usar [epochconverter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) para convertir las fechas a timestamp, ponerlas en tu base de datos y usar la query antes de modificar el modelo, asi vas probando.

Comment: gracias,realizare las pruebas a ver si funciona correctamente

Comment: hola @Gastón Saillén,he probado y funciona bien pero al probarlo en la pagina que pasas para hacer pruebas las fechas que me da es de un dia anterior,bueno da igual,lo importante era poder recoger esas fechas,gracias